# UITableView cells animation on scroll. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, ios-animations

Community, please help out a beginner! Can you tell me how to make such animation for TableView cells?
Thank!

[cell animation as in this video with Swift](https://youtube.com/shorts/6Rt5m5fZu00?feature=share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives something similar to what you want. You might need to make adjustments to it or improve the code snippet.
You can work with the **panGestureRecognizer** property of the tableView

```
tableView.panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPan(_:)))
```

With this handler:

```
    @objc func didPan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard gesture.state == .changed else { return }

        let loc = gesture.location(in: tableView)
        guard let touchedCellIndex = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: loc) else { return }
        let n = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        guard touchedCellIndex.row < n - 1 else { return }
        
        if gesture.translation(in: tableView).y < 0 {
            for (index, cell) in tableView.visibleCells.enumerated() {
                guard let ip = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
                if ip.row > touchedCellIndex.row {
                    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: -gesture.velocity(in: tableView).y * 0.02 * tanh(CGFloat(index)))
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05 * Double(index), delay: 0.0) {
                        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                    }
                }
                
            }
        } else {
            for (index, cell) in tableView.visibleCells.reversed().enumerated() {
                guard let ip = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
                if ip.row < touchedCellIndex.row {
                    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: -gesture.velocity(in: tableView).y * 0.02 * tanh(CGFloat(index)))
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05 * Double(index), delay: 0.0) {
                        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

I am sure you can optimize this approach and make it more concise.

Comment: thank! It looks similar, but there is one major problem. You work only with visible cells. Therefore, the animation only works on neighboring cells. And it is necessary that the cells that are not visible are pulled up too. Is it possible? Can I somehow get an array of all cells and apply to it?

Comment: If you want to apply this strategy to all cells, you first need to get all cells: Suppose that you already have the table data in an array (e.g. tableDataArray). You then iterate over the data array and create index path for each (e.g. IndexPath(row: i, section: 0) assuming the i is the iterating variable and you are in section 0. Similar to what I did, you then divide the array of . Once you have the index path for a cell, you use tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) to get the cell. Then you apply the transformation to the cell.

Comment: Note: when you scroll down, you might want to apply the transformation only to the cell under the touch point. In that case, you should first divide the cells into two sets i.e. those above and those under the touched cell. It's pretty easy to do since you have the cell and index path for the touched cell (as I did in the example) and you have the array of the table data (or the array of all index paths).